# How to detect self-collision in Spline Curve?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am programming a random generated spline curve by first generating control points and then interpolate with spicy.splev.[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrO4p.jpg) is an example.

Now I want to check:

a) If the spline is colliding with it self.
b) if a) I want to get the angle of intersection.

The points are stored in a numpy array like:

```
np.array =[[  1.00000000e+01  -4.65000000e+02]
           [  1.78319153e+01  -4.60252579e+02]
          ...]
```

Any idea how to approach this? Would it be an option to check for each line segment if it collides with any other from the spline? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Depending on how many segments you ave checking them against each other would definitely option? Are you concerned about performance or why haven't you tried that?

Comment: I could lower the amount of lines for testing and later increase them. I tried some approaches but collinear lines were the bottleneck.I think 500 segments should be manageable? A solution with numpy operators would be best. But I think testing each line segments against each other should be the most sufficient solution for my problem.

Comment: Why is collinearity a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7901/adc2981df1f4f1857584da32ef86da9e0928.pdf and also the reference to Lasser in http://web.mit.edu/hyperbook/Patrikalakis-Maekawa-Cho/node112.html

Also:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080824/detection-of-self-intersection-point-of-curve in which @Narasimham cites:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338480/find-the-point-where-equations-x-t2-t-and-y-t3-3t-1-cross-itself?rq=1